# Uniface - Fatal error: 8011 - A license could not be acquired for UW10;UWALL;UW32

Tags: ide, uniface

I want to open the integrated development environment of Uniface 10 and I get the following error:

`Fatal error: 8011 - A license could not be acquired for UW10;UWALL;UW32.`

[image]

How can I solve this problem to start the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the Uniface session is not able to acquire the Licence. Check the assignment file $LICENSE_OPTIONS under SETTINGS section. It should point to your Licence service (DLM for 10.3.02 or below and RMS for 10.3.3 and above)